# CNN that generate a new image from input image

Tags: machine-learning

CNN such that outputs the image with the feature added to the input image can be created?
For example, if an image of a person's face is input, outputs an image of the person's face wearing glasses.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several options but basically the same way that you have one input for every pixel you must have one output from every pixel in the output image.

- In MLPs you must have the same neurons in the input layer than in the output layer.
- In CNNs you can also have at the beginning convolutional layers and after that deconvolutional layers.
- Take a look at this paper (it is awesome) to create very realistic images from other images (for example satellite and map views in google maps). It is a neural network that is trying to solve the problem and also trying to create images that other neural network is not capable to distinguish from real images (it also have the source code available):

https://phillipi.github.io/pix2pix/

Answer (score 1):

To add to the answer above, another way of doing this is neural style transfer, where we feed two images to a CNN which then generates a new image combining the content from the second image and the style from the first. Check out this paper for further details, https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.06576

We could of course always use [GAN](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.2661)s to do achieve full perfection.